# Removing files in app data windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to free up space on my windows 10 laptop. When I remove some programs I still see some of the files in AppData and before I just delete them I wanted to know, is there any good tool I can use that will safely delete them? i.e. figure what files here I don't need any more?  Or if there is a better way than manual deletion.

Comment: Manual deletion is the best way, as you can identify any data, that isn’t required. I suspect there isn’t that much stored in the 3 AppData directories

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an uninstaller to uninstall a product, including
its leftovers.
The uninstaller might miss some files, but usually it does a very good
job of getting everything.

An example is
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/),
which I also use.

Comment: Also, the "geek uninstaller" might do a better job than most default uninstallers of programs: https://geekuninstaller.com